# MySQL IF THEN condition to Drop a table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am trying to use stored procedure and check on a particular table and use IF THEN condition to drop the table. Is it possible to issue the DROP statement in the conditional block?

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE FC_SQLF()

BEGIN

DECLARE SQLFOUND int;

SET @SQLFOUND = (select count(table_name) from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'testdb' and table_name = 'temp_table');
IF @SQLFOUND = 1 THEN DROP TABLE testdb.abcd;
END IF;

END $$
```

Comment: Why not use `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testdb.abcd`

Comment: I don't think DROP TABLE IF EXISTS will work as I am doing conditional check on an another table.  Any other suggestions...

Comment: What is not working in your current code?

Comment: Check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4dbf/1).